# TypeError: pipeline[(pipeline.length - 1)] is undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running mongodb queries dynamically I am getting this error :

```
TypeError: pipeline[(pipeline.length - 1)] is undefined :
```

The following is my query :

```
var a = { "aggregate" : "income", "pipeline" : [ {$match:{sal : {$gt : 10000}}},{ "$skip" : 0}, { "$limit" : 5000 }], "cursor" : { "batchSize" : 5000 } };
    if(a["aggregate"] != undefined)
    {
        var collectionName = a["aggregate"];
        var query = a["pipeline"];
                print(query)
            for(var k = 0;k<query.length;k++)
            {
                var b = query[k]
                if(b["$skip"] != undefined)
                {
                    delete query[k];
                }
                if(b["$limit"] != undefined)
                {
                    delete query[k];
                }
               
            }   
            print(query)
         db.getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(query)
    }
```

Please help

Regards

Kris

Comment: This is a code problem, not a mongoDB problem

Comment: @nimrodserok can u pls get me in which line of code there is a problem and also code snippet, thanks, kris

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer may help someone:

```
var a = { "aggregate" : "income", "pipeline" : [ {$match:{sal : {$gt : 10000}}},{ "$skip" : 0}, { "$limit" : 5000 }], "cursor" : { "batchSize" : 5000 } };
if(a["aggregate"] != undefined)
{
    var collectionName = a["aggregate"];
    var foo = [];
    var query = a["pipeline"];
            print(query)
        for(var k = 0;k<query.length;k++)
        {
            var b = query[k]
            if(b["$skip"] != undefined)
            {
                delete query[k];
            }
            else if(b["$limit"] != undefined)
            {
                delete query[k];
            }
            else
            {
             foo.push( query[k]);

            }

           
        }   
        
     db.getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(foo)
}
```